# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SDL2.obj'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to install SDL but it keeps on bring up this error in visual 
    studio 2013, any suggestions?

```
//Code

#include <SDL\SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

return 0;
}

//Error

//1>------ Build started: Project: Graphics, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
//1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SDL2.obj'
//========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped      ==========
```

Comment: This is linking error. Please specify the path of SDL2 in linking property

Comment: I checked the additional dependencies in the input tab in and i have the following: SDL2
SDL2main

Comment: Here's a more understanding comment i checked in Project->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies and found SDL2;SDL2;main;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621308/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-opencv-calib3d220d-obj

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the complete name of the library that you want to add as "Additional Dependencies". The path where libraries have to be looked up are set in "Additional Library Directories".

Replace `SDL2` with `SDL2.lib` in that field.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong SDL2 download. Use the VC build, not the mingw when using Visual Studio. You will find the *.lib files within that download that you need.